# Triune brain model

Tags: evolution, brain

I have heard about the triune brain model in biology class, but my teacher does not know much about it. What I'm curious about, is this model accepted by most of the neuroscientists, or is it just a mere hypothesis? And should I learn more about it? Although I think it's an interesting topic, I won't put efforts in finding all the info on the net, if not necessary.